# Javascript Callback Function Problems

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, primes

Offering a bounty to anybody who solves.  PM me first before posting solution to discuss amount.

What I would like to do is have a loop checking param.result.  The asynchronous call is being made to stepping_isProbablePrime.  This returns a close to me which I use in the return of the checkPrime function.  However, I'm not sure how to access result once I've called this function, I'd like to keep it to check for primality during a loop.  Everytime I try to access result it is either null or unidentified.

```
var findPrime = function(checkPrime, result)
{
    var inParam = null; 
    var prime = new BigInteger("7", 10);

    checkPrime(prime, result);
    alert(inParam);
}

var result = function(param1)
{
    inParam = param1
    return param1;
}

var checkPrime = function(p2,result)
{
    var inParam = null;
    var closure= p2.stepping_isProbablePrime(5);
    var receiver = function(scope,param,subparam) 
    {
        result( param.result );
        return BREAK;
    };
    return ( [ closure, receiver, EXIT ] ).ready().frequency(1).timeout(1).go();
};

var timerID = findPrime(checkPrime, result);
}
```

Included below is the method call stepping_isProbablePrime(t):

```
BigInteger.prototype.stepping_isProbablePrime = function (t) {
BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime:create" );
var self = this;
var x = self.abs();
var et1 = ElapsedTime.create();
var et2 = ElapsedTime.create();
return [
    function(scope,param,subparam) {
    BigInteger.log("stepping_isProbablePrime No.1: " );

    et1.start( "stepping_isProbablePrime" );

    var i;
    if( x.t == 1 && x[0] <= lowprimes[ lowprimes.length-1 ] ) {
        for ( i = 0; i < lowprimes.length; ++i )
        if ( x[0] == lowprimes[i] ) {
            BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime.1 EXIT" );
            //return true;
            param.result = true;
            return EXIT;
        }
        BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime.2 EXIT" );
        // return false;
        param.result = false;
        return EXIT;
    }

    if ( x.isEven() ) {
        BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime.3 EXIT" );
        // return false;
        param.result = false;
        return EXIT;
    }

    i = 1;
    while ( i < lowprimes.length ) {
        var m = lowprimes[i];
        var j = i+1;
        while( j < lowprimes.length && m < lplim ) {
        m *= lowprimes[j++];
        }

        m = x.modInt(m);
        while( i < j ) {
        if( m % lowprimes[i++] == 0 ) {
            BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime:4 EXIT" );
            // return false;
            param.result = false;
            return EXIT;
        }
        }
    }

    BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime:5 BREAK" );
    return BREAK;
    },

    // // ver1>>
    // function(scope,param,subparam) {
    //  BigInteger.log("stepping_isProbablePrime No.2:called:" + param.result );
    //  // return x.millerRabin(t);
    //  et2.start("isProbablePrime.millerRabin");
    //  var result = x.millerRabin(t);
    //  et2.stop();
    //  et1.stop();
    //  param.result = result;
    //  return BREAK;
    // },
    // // ver1<<

    // ver2>>
    function(scope,param,subparam) {
    BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime No.2: calling millerRabin : subparam.result=" + subparam.result );
    et2.start("isProbablePrime.millerRabin");
    subparam.result=null;
    return x.stepping_millerRabin(t).BREAK();
    },
    function(scope,param,subparam) {
    BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime No.3: returning millerRabin : subparam.result=" + subparam.result );
    et2.stop();
    et1.stop();
    param.result = subparam.result;
    BigInteger.log( "stepping_isProbablePrime No.3: param.result=" + param.result );
    return BREAK;
    },
    // ver2<<
    EXIT
].NAME("stepping_isProbablePrime");
};
```

Comment: What are `BREAK`, `EXIT`, and `.ready().frequency(1).timeout(1).go()` from? These are not native javascript. It would also help to see the source of `stepping_isProbablePrime`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't swear I've followed your code, but I think the immediate problem is that you have three different variables named "inParam": a global one, one local to findPrime and one local to checkPrime.  When the result function sets the value of inParam, it's setting the global one, but when findPrime uses inParam, it's using it's local variable.

Using global variables for dataflow is usually a bad idea, though.  It tends to make brittle code that fails if things overlap in ways that look harmless.  You'd probably be better off finding a way to use return values.  Or if you can't manage that, a callback or output parameter.